# Atom autoclose-html how to force inline closing tags

Tags: ide, atom-editor

Brand new to Atom. I see that I can force some html tags to close inline using the autoclose-html package. However, when I populate the list with tags to close inline, they are still closing on a separate line. How should the list be formatted? I see the defaults as

`default: ['title', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']`

And so I first tried adding `...'p', 'span']` to the list, and it did not work. I then found a list in autoclose-html.coffee and added the same, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The way I did this (Mac OS - should be same for other OS's):

- Bring up Atom Settings (Atom menu --> Preferences)
- Select Packages
- Select autoclose-html Settings
- Select View Code

[image: "View Code"]

- Expand the lib folder
- Select configuration.coffee

[image: "configuration.coffee"]

- Make your changes in there and save the file.
- Restart Atom

All done!

Comment: I just disable this package and the code autocomplete still works. Looks like something else control this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have fix this issue. I just work it out.
It's nothing about this package, it's handled by atom's html-language plugin. Just open Atom->Snippets and add the following codes:

Sorry the preview looks terrible when I post the code as text. So I post a image here.

[image]